# Getting Javadoc generation to include annotation-specific formatting in the summary table

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

I'm using something similar to Guava's [`@Beta`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) annotation to mark interfaces/classes/methods as not-ready-for-release (and I have an `@Alpha` annotation too).

Is there a way to get this to do something special (e.g. add a CSS class "beta" so I can color it yellow or add a caution icon or something) in the method summary table?

Look at the Guava docs for [`com.google.guava.base.Predicates`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html). The method `Predicates.assignableFrom()` is marked `@Beta` but this only appears in the detailed method description, not the summary table.

Comment: AFAIK you'd need to write a custom doclet to do anything remark(up)able in the output.

Comment: I don't know; I've never written one that did anything interesting with the generated markup. I wouldn't think so, but I also don't know how much of the standard one you'd be able to use.

Comment: I think you can just extend the standard doclet but overwrite certain Method outputs to add the annotations.